# int $0x80 in Programming From The Ground Up

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I recently started reading [Programing From The Ground Up (PDF)](http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.2012011000.pdf), but I've run into an issue in the first program. The program is very simple:

```
.section .data
.section .text

.globl _start

_start:
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    $0, %ebx
    int     $0x80
```

But in compiling and running I get the error `Illegal Instruction: 4`. I did edit the program so that it would compile properly (removed the two `.section`s and changed `_start` to `_main`) so that may have affected it.

I am using the x86_64 instruction set (Intel processor).

Comment: This code works fine for me (on Linux). What OS are you on? Although, why do you call `fork` (2) syscall? Maybe, you need `exit` syscall (1)?

Comment: Ah, that was a typo. Im on Mac OS 10.7. Changing it to 1 didn't help. How are you compiling? I've just been using `gcc`.

Comment: That compiles alright, but when linking: `$ ld exit -o exit/
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specificed, assuming 10.7/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:/
  "start", referenced from:/
     -u command line option/
     (maybe you meant: _start)/
ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture x86_64`

Comment: If your code is in exit.s, try `as exit.s -o exit.o && ld exit.o -o exit`

Comment: can some one point our what is the meaning of .section data,.section text, and movl $1,%eax does the instruction movl $1,%eax stores the system call or system call corresponding to value $1 is stored in $eax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using x86-64, you need to change the ABI slightly, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730064/process-command-line-in-linux-64-bit). For a very nice summary of the differences, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535989/what-are-the-calling-conventions-for-unix-linux-system-calls-on-x86-64) post.